# DataGrigView convert to DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to convert DataGridView to DataTable but all sollution which I have found didnť work. Any idea? Or need I use foreach etc.?

```
        DataTable d = detailsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable;// return null table

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)detailsDataGridView.DataSource;//doesn't work

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = detailsDataGridView.DataSource;
        DataTable d = (DataTable)(bs.DataSource);//doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Try This Method, This is What you need:

```
DataTable data = GetDataTableFromDGV(dgvMyMembers);

    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (!column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(column.Name);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

**OR**

Here's a quick example solution with a simple 2 column DataGridView

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Column.Add("column1", typeof(string));
 dt.Column.Add("column2", typeof(string));

foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvR in myDataGridView)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(dgvR.Cells[0].Value, dgvR.Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: So there is no sollution without foreach?

Comment: Just try it, Always keep in mind when you find a code working.. then it works and your problem is solved :)

Comment: There will be a problem because I have one method for more DataGridViews with different names and count of Columns.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution in one line. Hope this will help

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvR.DataSource;
```