# Datatable from Datagridview(databinding)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I make two datagridviews via [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx) a now I need to get datatable from "detailsDataGridView", but I can't convert it. 
Error: System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource can't be casted to type System.Data.DataTable.

Any idea?
The code, I have tried.

```
    DataTable d = detailsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
/////////////
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)detailsDataGridView.DataSource;
////////////
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = detailsDataGridView.DataSource;
        DataTable d = (DataTable)(bs.DataSource);
////////////
DataTable data = GetDataTableFromDGV(dgvMyMembers);

    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (!column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(column.Name);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: What is the name of your datagridview?

Comment: Like at msdn, detailsDataGridView and masterDataGridView.

Comment: But I want only datatable from detailsDataGridView.

Comment: I have tried it with correct parameter before. Failed at: var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();- same error

Comment: Have you set the detailsDataGridView Datasource?

Comment: Yes, like at msdn. If you want I would send you project.

Comment: [link](http://leteckaposta.cz/689218807) , it includes README, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method, This is What you need:

> The DataGridView name is detailsDataGridView, so you'll do this :
>
> DataTable data = GetDataTableFromDGV(detailsDataGridView);

Then data is the datatable!

```
    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (!column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(column.Name);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

You can see my answer to this Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130605/datagrigview-convert-to-datatable/16130664#16130664)

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer and I tried it. But it still throws error :System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource object can not be cast to type System.Data.DataTable.

Comment: Add what have you tried.. edit your question by adding the code!

Comment: Edited. I think the problem is databinding.